# Passing data to a UIView - failure

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I have a strange problem that I've never encountered before,
I have data in my viewController that I want to display in a UIView.

It's an iPad App which involve a SplitView Controller, when I click on an element within the table view (masterView) it execute a function in my detailViewController (via a protocol).

A function is executed which launch a UIView and send data to it:

myController:

```
- (void)SelectionChanged:(DocumentInfo*)document_info withDocu:(Document *)document{ 

    DocumentView *viewDoc=[[DocumentView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    viewDoc.doc=document;
    viewDoc.doc_info=document_info;
    [viewDoc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:viewDoc]; 
}
```

DocumentView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Document.h"
#import "DocumentInfo.h"

@class Document;
@class DocumentInfo;

@interface DocumentView : UIView

@property(strong,nonatomic) Document *doc;
@property(strong,nonatomic) DocumentInfo *doc_info;

@end
```

DocumentView.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {        
        UILabel *titreDoc=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 32, 339, 21)];
        titreDoc.textColor = [self makeColorRGB_RED:66 GREEN:101 BLUE:149];
        titreDoc.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:(24.0)];
        [self addSubview:titreDoc];
        NSLog(@"%@ - %@",doc,doc_info);
        titreDoc.text=@"Nouveau Document";
    }
    return self;
}
```

My view is well displayed (I mean the label appear) but impossible to get the data which would have been passed to it... (the NSLog print (null) (null) )

Anybody know the reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems pretty straight forward. You initialize your view (which means that you run `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`) and **after** that you're setting the data, so it's normal that you see `null` values into your `init` method because the ivars have not being set yet. What you could do is to modify your init method in order to construct your view taking into account these ivars. Something like this perhaps:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame doc:(Document *)doc docInfo:(DocumentInfo *)docInfo;
```

ps. If you choose to make your custom `init` method do not forget to call the designated initializer (`-initWithFrame:`) before any customization.

Comment: OMG you're right but i guessed we could just pass value like this and it just sets the data after ...  i'm bad :s thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Though, if you don't really care to use the values inside initialization you would be fine with your current code, you would just not able to inspect them in `init`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the NSLog prints null is because the doc and doc_info are nil when the initWithFrame method is called. The doc and doc_info properties are set after the initWithFrame method is called in selectionChanged: method. Add the NSLog function after line 3 in selectionChanged method like this:

```
- (void)SelectionChanged:(DocumentInfo*)document_info withDocu:(Document *)document{ 

  DocumentView *viewDoc=[[DocumentView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
  viewDoc.doc=document;
  viewDoc.doc_info=document_info;
  NSLog(@"%@ - %@",doc,doc_info);
 [viewDoc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[self.view addSubview:viewDoc];
```

}